# Understanding an inequality with supremum of minumum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A,B,C,D$ positive numbers, $g$ be a positive function, $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and the condition $Ag(x)+B\le g(x)^{\alpha}$ holds. Then the following is true:

$$AC+DB\le \min\left[ Cg(x)^{\alpha-1},Dg(x)^{\alpha} \right] 
\le\sup_{t>0}  \min\left[ Ct^{\alpha-1},Dt^{\alpha} \right] 
=C^{\alpha}D^{1-\alpha}.
$$

I am trying to understand these inequalities and equality. But i didn't manage it. It looks very complicated. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you didn't manage to understand? What have you tried? Can you prove part independently of the others?

Comment: @CalvinLin I try to write a formal proof but unfortunately i can not do anything. May be you can give me some hint for every part.

Comment: @user315531 $AC+DB\le \min\left[ Cg(x)^{\alpha-1},Dg(x)^{\alpha} \right]$ seems not true.
A counterexample: Let $A = \frac12, B = \frac13, C = 2, D = 3$ and $\alpha = \frac12$. Let $g(x) = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I found a mistake in my solution (step 1), which I will describe there.

**Step 1:** Proving
$AC+DB\le \min\left[ Cg(x)^{\alpha-1},Dg(x)^{\alpha} \right]$. Equivalently,

$$ AC+DB\le
\begin{cases}
Cg(x)^{\alpha-1}\le Dg(x)^{\alpha},  & D\ge C/g(x) \\
Dg(x)^{\alpha}\le Cg(x)^{\alpha-1}, & D\le C/g(x)
\end{cases}$$

Suppose $AC+DB>Cg(x)^{\alpha-1}$ when $D\ge C/g(x)$. Then $\color{red}{Dg(x)(A-g(x)^{\alpha-1})\ge C(A-g(x)^{\alpha-1})>-DB}$
, which implies that $Ag(x)+B> g(x)^\alpha$, which contradicts our initial assumption that $Ag(x)+B\le g(x)^\alpha$. Thus, the statement is true when $D\ge C/g(x)$. $\color{red}{\text{The issue with these inequalities is that}A-g(x)^{\alpha-1}\text{is necessarily negative.}}$

**Step 2:** Proving $\min\left[ Cg(x)^{\alpha-1},Dg(x)^{\alpha} \right] 
\le\sup_{t>0}  \min\left[ Ct^{\alpha-1},Dt^{\alpha} \right]$. This is the simplest step, and follows from the definition of $\sup$ and the fact that $g$ is a positive function.

**Step 3:** Proving $\sup_{t>0}  \min\left[ Ct^{\alpha-1},Dt^{\alpha} \right] 
=C^{\alpha}D^{1-\alpha}$ is a little tricky, and a graph helps. We take advantage of the fact that $\alpha-1<0<\alpha$. $t^\alpha$ will monotonically increase from the origin in an unbounded fashion, and $t^{\alpha-1}$ will monotonically decrease from the $t=0$ asymptote and tend to zero. Thus, these functions will intersect once for $t>0$. $\min\left[ Ct^{\alpha-1},Dt^{\alpha} \right]$ represents $Dt^{\alpha}$ until the point of intersection, and $Ct^{\alpha-1}$ after. Thus, $\sup_{t>0}  \min\left[ Ct^{\alpha-1},Dt^{\alpha} \right]$ represents the value at the point of intersection, which we can now solve for...

Comment: I'm trying to understand where all these inequalities are coming from. Could you provide detailed context to this problem? Also, are you willing to make some restrictions on the choice of $g$? I'm not sure if you can edit a bounty, but if you can please edit it to match the request.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an observation / clarification that is too long for a comment.A solution has already been provided in the answer of @DavidRaveh.

I will assume that the numbers $A,B,C,D$ are restricted to be strictly positive. Otherwise we could choose $B=0$ and $A$ large to make the inequality
$$
  AC + DB \leq C^\alpha D^{1-\alpha} \tag{1} \label{ineq}
$$
to be violated.

I initially thought that the inequality \eqref{ineq} can not be true, because it's left side depends on $A$ and $B$ whilst the right side does not, so choosing $A$ and $B$ high enough would violate the inequality \eqref{ineq}. However, the existence of a function $g$ gives us an upper bound on the values of $A$ and $B$: Notice that the inequality condition
$$
  A g(x) + B \leq g(x)^\alpha \label{cond} \tag{2}
$$
is satisfied whenever $g(x)\in [f_1(A,B),f_2(A,B)]$, where $f_{1,2}(a,b)$ are the two strictly positive roots of the equation $At+B=t^\alpha$, if they exist. This follows from the fact that $t\mapsto At+B$ is a linear function and $t\mapsto t^\alpha$ is a concave function. The two roots exist iff the linear function $t\mapsto At+B$ is not above the concave function $t\mapsto t^\alpha$ (and then also the function $g$ can exist), which gives us an upper bond on $A$ and $B$ that can be described as
$$
At+B \leq t^\alpha
$$
for some $t>0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your explanations are so complicated for me? You show that when $AC+DB\le \min\left[ Cg(x)^{\alpha-1},Dg(x)^{\alpha} \right]$ is true if $Ag(x)+B\le g(x)^{\alpha}$ holds. Am i right?

Comment: @user315531 Thanks for your feedback, I'm sorry I did not write very clear, I edited my answer a bit. Let me know if it is comprehensible now or what I could explain better. Essentially, as I state at the beginning, this is not a solution, it is only an explanation why the inequality (1) can  hold despite it is a bit contra-intuitive as there are no explicit restrictions on the parameters $A,B$.